# Linear regression for sales

Tags: regression, machine-learning

I retailer has three sales channel: pickup (pkup), home delivery (hd), and in store purchase (st). I want to see the impact of pkup and hd on total sales (TS) (= pkup + hd + st). I wonder if I can formulate it as TS = a*pkup + b*hd + c*st + d and simply do a linear regression. The issue I am struggling with is TS = pkup + hd + st. How do I check that if, say hd spend increases the TS as compared to say in store pickup?

Comment: When you do a regression analysis the estimated coefficients of the variables represent the change in the dependent variable (sales in your case) with a one unit increase of the corresponding independent variable, holding all the other variables constant. So you can just look at the coefficient to see that variable's individual effect on the dependent variable. Edit: if you have categorical predictors the coefficients that R will output are relative to the intercept

Comment: I doubt that the formula "TS = pkup + hd + st" is correct. At least it gave me a hard time understanding the question.

Comment: @MichaelM the formula is correct. Every individual buys through one of the channels (pkup, hd, st) and TS is simiply the total purchase. The question is if people buy more if they buy by pkup and/or hd. If yes, then how much more as compared to when they byuy using st channel (that is in store purchase).